# Geometry nodes Flatten by average normals

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to use geometry nodes to flatten the mesh by the average normals, kinda like looptool's flatten option. But I have two issues : The first one, the mesh rotates by 90 degrees. The second one, there is an offset. I figured both issues could be linked, but I have no idea why it happens

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u just try to use blur?

Comment: @Chris No I haven't tried, where would I use it?

Comment: like this:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXcDK.gif

Comment: thank you, however i wont be able to get the result I'm looking for with this method since it breaks the original shape. This behaves more like a smooth modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Do you want something like this?

[image]

It uses vector projection to move all points to the mean normal axis and then calculates the offset from the mean position also projected to the mean normal axis.

[image: node tree]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve